# automatic placement of a wrapfigure at the margin in a twopage desing

Tags: double-sided, wrapfigure

Using a twoside design in scrbook calls into question an automatic placement of a `\wrapfigure` at the margin opposite to the bookbinding.

```
\documentclass[twoside=true]{scrbook}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Is there a automatic solution or parameter?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Could you provide a manual MWE to be automated?

Comment: Do you think it is best practise to place it always right from a typography point of view?

Comment: If you use the `o` option rather than `r` or `l`, it will always be on the outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wrapfig` package provides placement options `o` and `i` in addition to `r` and `l`, for `outside` and `inside` respectively. So you just need to use the appropriate option (`o` in this case):

```
\documentclass[twoside=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image: outside edges]